# AES-256-CBC encryption Node.Js but fails to Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, pdf, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt array of objects using aes-256-cbc but its not happening:

```
let key = new Buffer(SSO_key, 'base64');//decoding key in base64
let IV = new Buffer(SSO_IV, 'base64');//decoding IV in base64

Text.push({
   pdf_text: get_content,//getting encrypted pdf here
   course_id: "123",
   candidate_id: "123",
   time_stamp: new Date()
 })

Text = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(Text));

let cipher1 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, IV);
let get_content1 = cipher1.update(Text, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher1.final('base64');
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: See examples https://gist.github.com/jenrik/766f81a147d61b6a9557

Answer (score 0):

As long as `SSO_key`, when encoded in `base64` is 32 bytes long and `SSO_IV`, when encoded `base64` is 16 bytes long, your code should work.

I tried the code below, which is as close as possible to the one you have:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
let key = Buffer.alloc(32, 0); //new Buffer("asdakjdsh", 'base64');//decoding key in base64
let IV = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);

let Text = [];
Text.push({
   pdf_text: "get_content",//getting encrypted pdf here
   course_id: "123",
   candidate_id: "123",
   time_stamp: new Date()
 })

Text = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(Text));

let cipher1 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, IV);
let get_content1 = cipher1.update(Text, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher1.final('hex');

console.log(`==========getcontent`, get_content1);
```

And the output is:

```
==========getcontent 367bbed3d629faa8baaad6f9116277006b9b6b8fa80226e04d1bcdbda444b63054dc6250cb1920604988a48b6508dd96b2ec08382921146a71e914aa9e94f2a14fa598ee4aeda064e15020a7791b1e4db513b94f59d7df19d612c66616683075a1d7a7e8f66a2d341c0a234d2c3b4cea
```

Comment: My pdf size is 1 MB but after encryption the "get_content1" size is around 8 MB.

Comment: decrypt it and see if you get back the original PDF

Comment: @Gaurav What's the size of the stringified variable `Text` *before* encrypting it? You also encode to hex, which doubles the size of the output compared to binary.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Hi actually i have to encrypt in nodejs and decrypt in php for that i have made changes like instead of hex i have changed it to base64 as by default in php it works like that. Also we are using same Key and IV to encrypt and decrypt. But the problem which i am facing is in node js it encrypts the data but in php it doesnt decrypt the same.